# php won't insert into mysql. no errors

Tags: php, mysql

I create php and mysql database and table. This is my code:

```html
<form action="proba.php" method="post" />
 <p> ime: <input type="text" name="ime" /></p>
    <p> prezime: <input type="text" name="prezime" /></p>
    <p> datum rodjenja: <input type="text" name="godiste" /></p>
    <p> jmbg: <input type="text" name="jmbg" /></p>
    <p> adresa: <input type="text" name="adresa" /></p>
    <p> email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
    <p> telefon: <input type="text" name="telefon" /></p>
    <p> datum: <input type="text" name="datum" /></p>
    
    <input  type="submit" value="insert" />
</form>
```

and here is my code to connect with mysql

```html
<?php


$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "1511", "test");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;

$db_selected = mysql_select_db ('test', $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
 die('nedostupno ' . test . ' : ' . mysql_error ());
 
}

$values = $_POST['ime'];
$values2 = $_POST['prezime'];
$values3 = $_POST['godiste'];
$values4 = $_POST['jmbg'];
$values5 = $_POST['adresa'];
$values6 = $_POST['email'];
$values7 = $_POST['telefon'];
$values8 = $_POST['datum'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (ime, prezime, godiste, jmbg, adresa, emal, telefon, datum) VALUES ('values', 'values2', 'values3', 'values4', 'values5', 'values6', 'values7', 'values8')";

}
echo 'Connected successfully';

?>
```

And this is mysql:

[image: mysql]

Comment: you didn't executed your code . $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

Comment: You're also mixing mysql_* and mysqli_* functions, which you can't do.

Comment: mixture of mysql and mysqli code + query didn't fired ..

Comment: You added all code in wrong `if` condition. You added everything in condition where `!$link` . Your code means that If your mysqli connection is not successful, then only do all the required tasks of insertion. Thats not possible and is wrong. Also you didn't execute your sql query.

Comment: ok, thank you all. i will delete it and start from begining. i will learn more about mysqli because when put mysqli this erroe is gone http://prnt.sc/cimy2l

Comment: You might also want to take a read of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-ph) as your code is vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made some few mistakes so that the query might not be inserting datas into the phpmyadmin database. The basic error you have made is in the insert query by not concatenating the values that you want in the `VALUES` section and the insert statement syntax will be like this.

**Insert Syntax:**

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

> **Note:** If a column is AUTO_INCREMENT (like the "id" column) or TIMESTAMP (like the "reg_date" column), it is no need to be specified in the SQL query; MySQL will automatically add the value.

So the basic form will be the same as you display in the question. I have added a name alone to the submit button and re-modified it.

**HTML FORM:**

```
<form action="proba.php" method="post" />
    <p> ime: <input type="text" name="ime" /></p>
    <p> prezime: <input type="text" name="prezime" /></p>
    <p> datum rodjenja: <input type="text" name="godiste" /></p>
    <p> jmbg: <input type="text" name="jmbg" /></p>
    <p> adresa: <input type="text" name="adresa" /></p>
    <p> email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
    <p> telefon: <input type="text" name="telefon" /></p>
    <p> datum: <input type="text" name="datum" /></p>    
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="insert" />
</form>
```

And your `proba.php` will look like this as i have coded below.

```
<?php
//Database connection Part of Mysqli
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="1511";
$db="test";
$conn=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);
// Print Error if the connection is failed.
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// Print Error if the DB is not selected.
if (!mysqli_select_db($conn, $db)) {
    die("Uh oh, couldn't select database --> $db" . $conn->connect_error . ' >');
}
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $values = $_POST['ime'];
    $values2 = $_POST['prezime'];
    $values3 = $_POST['godiste'];
    $values4 = $_POST['jmbg'];
    $values5 = $_POST['adresa'];
    $values6 = $_POST['email'];
    $values7 = $_POST['telefon'];
    $values8 = $_POST['datum'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`ime`, `prezime`, `godiste`, `jmbg`, `adresa`, `emal`, `telefon`, `datum`) VALUES ('".$values."', '".$values2."', '".$values3."', '".$values4."', '".$values5."', '".$values6."', '".$values7."', '".$values8."')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    echo 'Inserted successfully';
}
?>
```

> Note: You first put **echo** to the Insert Statement and then break the execution by putting the **exit;** and you copy the statement that is echoed and place it in SQL of the DB and then check whether any error occurs in insertion. If no error occurs remove the echo and delete the exit;

And you are inserting the data successfully. Hope so i would have given a clear explanation about the data not inserting into the database.

Comment: i tried with with your code and got this http://prntscr.com/cir589
now i will kill myself :D

Comment: Sorriee bro. Change this line to $conn=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db); as i give below

Comment: $conn=new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);

Comment: and try now this is the error and we shall crack through

Comment: @SandiBudic. Sorriee for mistake bro :)

Comment: i can give you teamviewer id and pass to look if you want... i dont have f**** idea :D

Comment: You provide me with the team-viewer details and i shall make a try at this :)

Comment: Have you used any password for local-host in wamp server at the time of installations:)

Comment: i put pass later.. i didnt got that opinion during instalation

Comment: Bro. one second . It shows you are using higher version i shall update the team-viewer and connect yours

Comment: The password you entered is incorrect. Pls try again :( Provide me with correct password bro

Comment: @SandiBudic. What help needed. Can you share :)

Comment: @ Naresh Kumar.P i was have problem with database and stupid inserting and i solve it... :D i will need help later with some reports... send me empty email to dexter87@gmail.com i cant find text doc where i did save your :D

Comment: brooo i got project... but i need your help if yiu want to work together. :)

Comment: I have mailed to the above mail id that you have given. Thanks. We shall discuss over there.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
$values = $_POST['ime'];
$values2 = $_POST['prezime'];
$values3 = $_POST['godiste'];
$values4 = $_POST['jmbg'];
$values5 = $_POST['adresa'];
$values6 = $_POST['email'];
$values7 = $_POST['telefon'];
$values8 = $_POST['datum'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (ime, prezime, godiste, jmbg, adresa, emal, telefon, datum) VALUES ('".$values."', '".$values2."', '".$values3."', '".$values4."', '".$values5."', '".$values6."', '".$values7."', '".$values8."')";
mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

Comment: i tried it but no changes.. i will delete all and start from begening. thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the very first mistake.

- You have added your success code in if condition where Server
  connection object is gets fail to connect.
- When you are using mysqli_connect for server connection then why
  you are using mysql_connect.
- Missing of query execution line. i.e. mysqli_query($link, $sql).

Comment: i was tried to use mysql_connect but i got this error http://prntscr.com/cimy2l
then i put mysqli_connect and error is gone... 
im very new in this and i dont know differences too much about mysql and msqli. 
it is still chinese language for me but im learning. :D

Comment: Did your issue with inserting records in database fixed!?

Comment: im tring something new with mysqli only and some other codes but still nothing. here is my new codehttp://prntscr.com/cinite
im little woried... im that much stupid :D

Comment: If you are still getting white page and not see the inserted records then please try to get mysqli query errors. it will definatly shows you an error. Do little R&D for mysqli query erros to print